# Why is this code crashing my browser?

Tags: javascript

The following code suppose to take a starting location and create an array of other locations around it and it's distance to them. I tried to debug, but the crash happens at the very beginning of this code execution (on latest chrome and firefox).

```
function makeRoads(){
    try {
        if(arguments.length%2 == 0){throw "you need to specify bla!";}
        else {
            var origin = arguments[0]
            for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i+2) {
                var destenation = arguments[i];
                var distance = arguments[i+1];
                makeRoad(origin, destenation, distance);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    finally{
        console.log("fianlly!!");
    }
}

function makeRoad(origin, destenation, distance) {
    function addRoad(origin, destenation) {
        if (!(origin in roads)){roads[origin] = [];}
        roads[origin].push({to: destenation, distance: distance});
    }

    addRoad(origin, destenation);
    addRoad(destenation, origin);
}
```

I call it using `makeRoads("a"/*the origin*/,"b",3/*first destination and distance*/,"c",4)`

Comment: Works for me. How do you call makeRoads?

Comment: What kind of crash do you mean?  What line does this occur on?

Comment: Minor note: "destenation" should be "destination"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your for-loop!

```
for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i+2)
```

`i+2` never increments i. You need to do `i+=2`